# How does the MA lib determine the levels for what is significant or not for ACF?

Tags: time-series, arima, autocorrelation

I am going through this stats [course](https://web.archive.org/web/20160127045303/https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/node/48).

I can follow all the steps, but have question how the lib figures out what is significant for ACF. See "ACF for Simulated Sample Data", the graph has two blue lines just inside of 0.2 and -0.2. What is the theory for determining these two levels?

Answer (score 0):

You can compute these confidence intervals by yourself:

```
significance_level <- qnorm((1 + 0.95)/2)/sqrt(sum(!is.na(indata)))
```

You only have to change "indata" for the name of your dataset. 
The theory is that you check for outliers by looking at a normal distribution that you assume your data follows. So having the number of observations you can estimate these Confidence Intervals.

Comment: How does your answer align with the next chapter in the online course? https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/node/65